# How can I use open type font in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, css, branding

Can I use open type font in Sharepoint 2010 ?
Is Open Type font compatible?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

This question isn't much to do with SharePoint, and more generally a CSS question.

Have a look at this:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/02/the-font-face-rule-revisited-and-useful-tricks/

Comment: I know but i asked as I'm not to good in this area and taught maybe i would get some help on how to use Open Type font with Sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

if it's good enough with just @font-face (but this could be a crossbrowser problem) that's the easiest way. I have have tried sIFR3 and cufon in SharePoint with good results, and one of my collegues have used Font Squirrel with great result in SP2010.
/C